# Killing IP connections who "spam" with requests

Tags: webserver, spam

How can I go about killing IP connections that seem to be sending a lot of requests to the same url? Let's say I have someone who requests the same url for more than 10 times in 5 seconds, I want to "cool" him off. Any ideas on how it's done?

Answer (score 5):

On *nix, you can use fail2ban with a something like this in your jail.conf (100 requests in 30 seconds means a 5 minute ban). Of course, you'll have to adjust this for how many requests you expect from a legitimate user -- as @Jeff Ferland points out in the comments below, you need to account for the number of requests that you receive on a normal page load (e.g. you have a lot of images on the page).

```
[apache-spammer]

enabled = true
banaction = apache
port    = http,https
filter  = apache-spammer
logpath = /srv/*/log/access.log
maxretry = 100
findtime = 30
bantime = 300
```

and a filter like this in `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-spammer.conf`:

```
[Definition]

# Option:  failregex
# Notes.:  regex to match the request messages in the logfile. The
#          host must be matched by a group named "host". The tag "<HOST>" can
#          be used for standard IP/hostname matching and is only an alias for
#          (?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>[\w\-.^_]+)
#
failregex = ^<HOST>.*/path/to/content.html
```

This is **untested** -- you'll have to experiment a bit to find what works. **Watch your fail2ban.log** to verify that you aren't banning innocent users!

An alternative would be a firewall rule that rate-limits requests from a particular IP address.

Comment: See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/208341/is-it-possible-to-rate-limit-http-requests-with-iptables

Comment: 10 requests in 30 seconds is far too low, and that will match 10 requests of anything. Load a page with 9 images on it once and you're in the doghouse for five minutes.

Comment: and: http://serverfault.com/questions/310599/iptables-rate-limit-module-problem

Comment: @JeffFerland: I don't think so: the regex in the filter file will only match the URL(s) that you specify. So an innocent user requesting 200 images+scripts+css all at once won't be affected, just the malicious request for the same "content.html" 10 times in 30 seconds (or whatever N times in M seconds the OP wants to set as a bound). Just as long as the filter file doesn't specify a broad wildcard to match all the embedded content that an innocent user is going to pull on each page load.

Answer (score 2):

Would [mod_evasive](http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?page_id=442) be what you're looking for? It's focused on DoS attacks and limits the number of requests to a page per second. Otherwise, you might be able to adapt [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org) to help out.